# the function of that

Tags: that

In the sentence below:

[image: The sentence with brackets in blue, and "that" circled in blue]

Please tell me what does "that" function as here. I do not think it is a relative pronoun or something similar.

Comment: Though it would not be entirely correct you could substitute the word "Which" to give a similar meaning. the *that* only points to the world they are describing. I cannot understand what a relative pro*nounce* is.

Comment: 'It is of such height and such width that the doorway is too small' is an easier sentence to analyse.

Comment: In future, it's advisable to actually type the words out rather than adding a screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *What they proclaimed, these posters, was the existence of another*
> *world, of **such** modernity, **such** intensified energy and speed, of danger*
> *too, **that their local one of weatherboard houses and bakers’ carts,***
> ***unweeded pavements and trams that filled the night sky with electric***
> *sp**arks, seemed by comparison flimsy and becalmed**.*

"That" is subordinator functioning as a 'marker' of the declarative content clause in bold.

The content clause is called an indirect complement because although it follows the coordination of noun phrases "such modernity, such intensified energy and speed, of danger too" it is not this noun phrase that licenses it, but the two occurrences of "such" that modify the noun phrases.

In other words, "such" and "that" are in construction together. We can tell this because if "such" is dropped, the clause becomes ungrammatical.